# I love (the) rainy season(s)

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, colloquial-language

To mean 'rainy/winter/summer seasons' in general do we say:

1. I love **the** rainy/winter/summer season, or
2. I love rainy/winter/summer season**s**.

Comment: Note that "Winter" and "Summer" are proper nouns, while "rainy" is an adjective.  You wouldn't normally say "winter season".  You'd just say "Winter".  You would normally say "the rainy season".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summer, Winter, Spring and Fall are proper nouns.  As such, you would normally just say "Summer", not "Summer season".  And of course since it is a proper noun, you wouldn't use "the".

What you may find confusing is that the season names can also be used as adjectives.  For example, when discussing TV, you might refer to the "fall season".  But in that case, "fall" is an adjective that describes the type of TV season you are referring to.

"Rainy" is an adjective.  As such, you can use it to refer to a season.  Since "season" is a noun, you need "the", so you would say "the rainy season".

"Season" can refer to one of the four named seasons ("Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter") or any arbitrary period of days that occurs every year ("The Christmas season", "The rainy season", "The baseball season")

Overall, if you say "I love the rainy season", it will sound right.  If you say "I love Summer", it will sound right.  If you same "I love the summer season", an English speaker would think "summer season of what?"

Comment: yes, winter and summer are nouns, but it in not unusual to form the compound nouns "winter season" and "summer season", for example to refer to fashion or holidays... and it is perfectly normal to refer to "the summer season" in this context. It is unusual to use them to refer to the seasons themselves, but not ungrammatical.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. So it should be "I love summer/winter/spring/fall" and "I love the rainy season."

Answer (score 0):

You can just use, Summer or Winter. And Rainy Season.